# Check for cents in a payment amount

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to run a check on an input field for if the user has entered a cents amount. IF they have not I throw an error.

Example:

```
var paymentAmount = 1
if(paymentAmount.indexOf('.') == -1 ) error("Please add cent amount");
```

The above works for the example but what if the user was to add 2 decimals in by mistake. I want to be able to check for that too.

```
var paymentAmount = 1.00.2
```

In the above scenario only the first indexOf the decimal will be detected.

I also need to check if they have actual entered the cent amount after the decimal.

What's the best way to go about all these 3 checks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for this:

```
if (/^\d+(\.\d{2})?$/.test(paymentAmount)) {
    // Do something
}
```

[Here is a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uvFju/).

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
function validateDecimal(value) {
   var regex = new RegExp(/^\d*\.\d\d$/);
   if (regex.test(value)) {
        return true;
   } else {
       return false;
   }
}

if (validateDecimal(paymentAmount)) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var paymentAmount = parseFloat('1.00.0');
if ( paymentAmount % 1 === 0 ) {
    console.log('Cents required');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Math.floor(paymentAmount) == paymentAmount) {
    //it's a whole number
}
```